# Making vba userform with inputs and command button

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I made a macro (`commandbutton`), which is working (probably not the best solution, but it's working):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim myval As Variant
 Dim ws As Worksheet
  myval = InputBox("Zadaj číslo riadku:")
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
If StrPtr(result) = 0 Then
 ElseIf myval = vbNullString Then
Else
  ws.Range("F3").Value = myval
End If
 ws.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1
End Sub
```

Now I want to make a `USERFORM`. I made this:

[image: screen]

But now I'm stuck:

1. I don't know how to make an input from `textbox`.
   (there would be 3 inputs on Page1)
2. Problem is the loop. I want to make a loop - `input2` to `input3`. So for example: Input2.value = 1, Input3.value = 60, then I want a loop from 1 to 60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Textbox contains Text but a loop expect numbers. Try something like this:

```
Dim lngText1 as Long
Dim lngText2 as Long
Dim i as Long
If IsNumeric(Me.Controls("textbox2").Value) And isNumeric(Me.Controls("textbox3").Value) Then
  lngText1 = CLng(Me.Controls("textbox2").Value)
  lngText2 = CLng(Me.Controls("textbox3").Value)

  For i = lngText1 To lngText2
    'Your code
  Next i
Else
  MsgBox "Please insert numbers"
End If
```

Comment: What if the textboxes contain non-numeric data? Maybe a check for that instead of assuming they are numbers?

Comment: Addition of the numerical check to the code example

Comment: `istnumeric` ??

Comment: Should the `Sub` be continuing if they are not numeric?

Comment: IsNumeric() checks if a value is a number. I don't know your makro. But I think it shouldn't run withouit the loop. I show you how to get the textbox values as numbers for a loop. That was your question I think. There was a mistake in the if check. I fixed it.

Comment: It works. You solve the error with your question _istnumeric ??_ But I fixed it too now.

Answer (score 0):

Added an `Exit Sub` in case of error

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  Dim lngText1 as Long
  Dim lngText2 as Long
  Dim i as Long

  If Not IsNumeric(Me.Controls("textbox2").Value) Or Not IsNumeric(Me.Controls("textbox3").Value) Then
    MsgBox "Please insert numbers"
    Exit Sub
  End If

  lngText1 = CLng(Me.Controls("textbox2").Value)
  lngText2 = CLng(Me.Controls("textbox3").Value)

  For i = lngText1 To lngText2
    'Your code
  Next i

End Sub
```